# C - struct problems - writing

Tags: c, struct

I'm making a program in C, and I'mm having some troubles with memory, I think.

So my problem is: I have 2 functions that return a struct. When I run only one function at a time I have no problem whatsoever. But when I run one after the other I always get an error when writting to the second struct.

Function `struct item* ReadFileBIN(char *name)`  -- reads a binary file.
`struct tables* getMesasInfo(char* Filename)`    -- reads a text file.

My code is this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int numberOfTables=0;
int numberOfItems=0;

//struct tables* mesas;
//struct item* Menu;

typedef struct item{
    char nome[100];
    int id;
    float preco;
};
typedef struct tables{
    int id;
    int capacity;
    bool inUse;
};
struct tables* getMesasInfo(char* Filename){
    struct tables* mesas;
    char *c;
    int counter,numberOflines=0,temp=0;
    char *filename=Filename;
    FILE * G;
    G = fopen(filename,"r");
    if (G==NULL){
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    }
    else{
     while (!feof(G)){
     fscanf(G, "%s", &c);
     numberOflines++;
        }
    fclose(G);
    }  
    /* Memory allocate for input array */
    mesas = (struct tables *)malloc(numberOflines* sizeof(struct tables*));
    counter=0;
    G=fopen(filename,"r");
    while (!feof(G)){
        mesas[counter].id=counter;
        fscanf(G, "%d", &mesas[counter].capacity);
        mesas[counter].inUse= false;
        counter++;
    }
fclose(G);
numberOfTables = counter;
return mesas;
}

struct item* ReadFileBIN(char *name)
{
        int total=0;
        int counter;
        FILE *ptr_myfile;
        struct item my_record;
        struct item* Menu;
        ptr_myfile=fopen(name,"r");
        if (!ptr_myfile)
        {
            printf("Unable to open file!");
        }

        while (!feof(ptr_myfile)){
            fread(&my_record,sizeof(struct item),1,ptr_myfile);
            total=total+1;
        }
        numberOfItems=total-1;
        Menu = (struct item *)calloc(numberOfItems , sizeof(struct item));
        fseek(ptr_myfile, sizeof(struct item), SEEK_END);
        rewind(ptr_myfile);
        for ( counter=1; counter < total ; counter++)
        {
            fread(&my_record,sizeof(struct item),1,ptr_myfile);
            Menu[counter] = my_record;
            printf("Nome: %s\n",Menu[counter].nome);
            printf("ID: %d\n",Menu[counter].id);
            printf("Preco: %f\n",Menu[counter].preco);
        }
        fclose(ptr_myfile);
        return Menu;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct item* tt = ReadFileBIN("menu.dat");
    struct tables* t = getMesasInfo("Capacity.txt");
    getchar();
}**
```

the error that im getting is :

"Unhandled exception at 0x00411700 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000."

in "Menu[counter] = my_record;"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in these lines:

```
    numberOfItems=total-1;
    Menu = (struct item *)calloc(numberOfItems , sizeof(struct item));
    fseek(ptr_myfile, sizeof(struct item), SEEK_END);
    rewind(ptr_myfile);
    for ( counter=1; counter < total ; counter++)
```

First, you're setting `numberOfItems` to one *less* than the total. This is incorrect. You don't even need `numberOfItems`; since `total` has the number of lines in the file, the next line should really be `Menu = (struct item*) calloc(total, sizeof(struct item));`

Second, you're trying to use `Menu` as a one-based array in the for loop. C arrays are zero-based. You should have the for loop use `for (counter = 0; counter < total; counter++)`.

Finally, as Peter pointed out, in the first function you're allocating the wrong size of object. You need to malloc `numberOfLines*(sizeof(struct tables)` (not `sizeof(struct tables*)`.

Comment: Thanks to you and Péter, your solution helped me, the counter and the worng size of the object were the problem. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to allocate a memory block of the wrong size in `getMesasInfo()`: `sizeof(struct tables*)` gives you the size of the *pointer*, not that of the struct it is pointing to:

```
mesas = (struct tables *)malloc(numberOflines* sizeof(struct tables*));
```

So you can easily overwrite unallocated memory. The proper allocation should be

```
mesas = (struct tables *)malloc(numberOflines* sizeof(struct tables));
```

or, similar to how you allocate the other array in `ReadFileBIN()`:

```
mesas = (struct tables *)calloc(numberOflines, sizeof(struct tables));
```

Moreover, I don't know whether it's intentional or not, but in `ReadFileBIN()` you are allocating (1) and reading (2) one less record than the total number of records:

```
    numberOfItems=total-1;                                             // 1
    Menu = (struct item *)calloc(numberOfItems , sizeof(struct item)); // 1
    fseek(ptr_myfile, sizeof(struct item), SEEK_END);
    rewind(ptr_myfile);
    for ( counter=1; counter < total ; counter++)                      // 2
    ...
```

Since the loop counter is started from 1 (instead of 0 as is normal in C), you effectively execute the loop `total-1` times. That is, you read into elements 1 to `total-1` of the array. However, the real elements of the array are indexed from 0 to `total-2` so the very first element in the array is left uninitialized, and in the end you commit a buffer overflow error.

Comment: Indeed. @Catarrunas: remember you're allocating for an array of structs, and mesas is the pointer to the first element, so you allocate memory for numberoflines structs at that location.

We do need to know the exact error, though. Fix this issue and run again, and we'll see.

Answer (score 1):

To further illustrate Peter's point:

```
struct tables {
  int id;
  int capacity;
  int inUse; /* bool is not a C type */
};

int main()
{
  printf("sizeof: %d\n",sizeof(struct tables*));
  printf("sizeof: %d\n",sizeof(struct tables));

}
```

Will output:

```
sizeof: 4
sizeof: 12
```

Comment: I thought `stdbool.h` defines a `bool` type.

Comment: I'm sure something he includes typedefs it to something (or it wouldn't compile), but it isn't part of the C standard. I was really just trying to indicate that I had changed it to `int`.